# Automatically populate integral equations depending on the bounds given

Tags: python

I am calculating the area of 3 regions. I am doing this by calculating the area of each region and then adding them together.

The limits for integration are (1078.08, 1078.816), (1078.924, 1079.348), (1079.448, 1079.476). I am manually entering the index of the array "bounds" to calculate the integrals:

```
bounds = [1078.08, 1078.816, 1078.924, 1079.348, 1079.448, 1079.476]
area = -(integrate.quad(estimated_y, bounds[0], bounds[1])[0]) + (-(integrate.quad(estimated_y, bounds[2], bounds[3])[0])) + (-(integrate.quad(estimated_y, bounds[4], bounds[5])[0]))
```

**Given the list "bounds", I want the code to recognize how many regions I am calculating the area of and adjust the calculation accordingly. And then automatically input the array indexes into the integral equation.**

It is important to note that I want to apply this coding method to other examples and each example has a different number of regions, so "bounds" will vary in length. Also, "bounds" will always be in the correct order.

Example 1 (bounds = [1080, 1085, 1091, 1079])

Desired Result:

```
area = -(integrate.quad(estimated_y, 1080, 1085)[0]) + (-(integrate.quad(estimated_y, 1091, 1079)[0]))
```

Example 2 (bounds = [1090, 1095])

Desired Result:

```
area = -(integrate.quad(estimated_y, 1090, 1095)[0])
```

How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is implement a loop-and-accumulate pattern.  So set up a for-loop to loop over each group of bounds and keep an accumulation variable and add to it.

I *strongly* recommend you put the pairs of bounds into tuples to prevent confusion and add clarity.  (See below).  You could operate on `bounds` without doing this with a little fancy indexing, but not pythonic!

Short example with a "diff" function instead of integration...  YMMV.

```
bounds = [  (4, 10),
            (-5, 2),
            (0, 20) ]

def diff(low, high):
    return high-low

total_diff = 0

for bound in bounds:
    total_diff += diff(bound[0], bound[1])

print(f'the total accumulated diff is {total_diff}')

# the total accumulated diff is 33
```